Eclipse PHP built in server wrong path and cant find resources
CURRENT SETUP
Software
Windows 10
XAMPP (Apache, PHPMyadmin, Fillezilla, openssl etc.)
Eclipse Version: 2024-03 (4.31.0)
PHP Version 8.2.12
XDEBUG 3.3.2  
project path: G:xampp\\htdocs\\api\\project
php built in server path: https://localhost
project path settings:
project base path: api/project
https://localhost/api/project
server xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server>
    <Port name="HTTP/1.1" protocol="HTTP">8429</Port>
<PathMapping local="https://localhost/api/project" module="project" remote="G:\xampp\htdocs\api\project"/></Server>

Run as - Run on server does not work. It has a wrong path (without /api/ part) and even when correcting the path there are no files found.
run as - run on server
gives:
browser: Not Found The requested resource /project/login.php was not found on this server.
console:
[Fri Aug  2 11:19:18 2024] 127.0.0.1:64548 Accepted    [Fri Aug  2 11:19:18 2024] 127.0.0.1:64548 [404]: GET /project/login.php - No such file or directory    [Fri Aug  2 11:19:18 2024] 127.0.0.1:64548 Closing


run as - CLI application works
run as - web application works
browser: localhost:8429 - not found
localhost:8429/api/project - not found
terminal: ping localhost:8429 -not found
UPDATE: when trying to acces http:/localhost:8429/login.php it works as intended. This leaves only one of the problems: the link created by eclipse is http:/localhost:8429/project/login.php instead of http:/localhost:8429/login.php
How to fix this?

How did you Set up Eclipse PDT with PHP's built-in server? From what we know, it is not a feature of Eclipse itself. And for your app, ping is the wrong command, what you were perhaps looking for is the httping command or fire a http HEAD request to http://localhost:8429. cUrl is your friend

I installed eclipse via download. I downloaded the PDP parckage. I pointed to the PHP executable in the settings. Also pointed to the XDEBUG. I configured the php built in server via windows-preferences-php-servers. I configured the run configuration built in server. I configured the project paths in the project-properties-php-debug. I have verry limited knowldege regarding proper programing. Used to use only notepad++ and xampp. I try to get to the next level of configuration, but it is very complicated to know where to start. Don't understand the ping part. Will watch the curl part.

Confirm. Ignore ping, curl the things. PHP supports HEAD mehtod, curl, too. curl -i http://... that is. Check if you can get it run on the command line.

I have installed curl. When i run curl -i http://localhost:8429 i get: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: localhost:8429
Date: Mon, 05 Aug 2024 13:58:03 GMT
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.2.12
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Further, when i try http://localhost:8429/login.php it works. So the last problem is that the url is  http:/localhost:8429/project/login.php instead of http:/localhost:8429/login.php, or that the root of the server is in /api instead of /api/project/.

Your clear description of your observations sounds reasonable to us also in the analysis. Our next educated guess would be that the base URL can be configured in Eclipse so that Eclipse understands the mapping of a file within the project to the URL. In the XML this could be the local="https://localhost/api/project" part (e.g. removing /project at the end), but we do not have an Eclipse instance at hand to verify this information.
